# how to print the last three nodes of a linked list?

Tags: java, while-loop, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

My whole code to try to get the las three nodes of a linked list is:
Node class:

```
package com.company;

public class Node {

    public int data;
    public Node nextNode;

    public Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.nextNode = null;
    }

    public int getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Linked list class;

```
package com.company;
public class LinkedList {
    public Node head;
    public int size;

    public LinkedList() {
        this.head = null;
        this.size = 0;
    }

    public void add(int data) {
        Node node = new Node(data);
        if (head == null) {
            head = node;
        } else {
            Node currentNode = head;
            while(currentNode.nextNode != null) {
                currentNode = currentNode.nextNode;
            }
            currentNode.nextNode = node;
        }
        size++;
    }
    
    public void printData() {
        Node currentNode = head;

        while(currentNode != null) {
            int data = currentNode.getData();
            System.out.println(data);
            currentNode = currentNode.nextNode;
        }
    }

    public void printLastThree(){
        Node currentNode = head;
        int i = this.size - 3;
        while(i <= this.size) {
            int data = currentNode.getData();
            System.out.println(data);
            currentNode = currentNode.nextNode;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
package com.company;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();

        ll.add(1);
        ll.add(2);
        ll.add(3);
        ll.add(4);
        ll.add(5);
        ll.add(6);
        ll.add(7);
        ll.add(8);
        ll.add(9);
        ll.add(10);
        ll.add(11);
        ll.add(12);
        
        ll.printData();
        System.out.println();
        ll.printLastThree();
    }
}
```

As you can see, in the `linked list` class I try to print the last three nodes of the linked list with the `printLastThree()` method, but in console I just get:

```
1
2
3
4
```

And I would like to get:

```
10
11
12
```

Can you say me what I am doing wrong?
I try in `printLastThree()` method to get the total size of the linked list and substract 3 positions, and then get to the total size of the linked list, but that doesn't work.
Thanks.

Comment: Think about what effect the value of `i` has on the identity of the node which you print out. Run your code under the debugger to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once can see from your code that `currentNode` starts as the `head` node, and its value gets printed in the first iteration of the loop. This is not what you want.

You'll first have to *skip* nodes, which do *not* get printed. You already calculated how many such nodes need to be skipped (`this.size - 3`), so you only need to add the loop to actually skip that many nodes:

```
    public void printLastThree(){
        Node currentNode = head;
        // First SKIP nodes (not to be printed)
        for (int i = size - 3; i > 0; i--) {
            currentNode = currentNode.nextNode;
        }
        // ...and only then start printing
        while (currentNode != null) {
            int data = currentNode.getData();
            System.out.println(data);
            currentNode = currentNode.nextNode;
        }
    }
```

You can also do it with one loop, and make the printing *conditional* on the current index:

```
    public void printLastThree(){
        Node currentNode = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (i >= size - 3) { // Are we at the last three nodes?
                int data = currentNode.getData();
                System.out.println(data);
            }
            currentNode = currentNode.nextNode;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the bug is in printLastThree().

You need to move the currentNode from head to position: size-3; But don't print it just yet.

Then after that, move again from size-3 to size-1 and during this move, print it out.

try 2 while loops. Later you can also make it into 1 while loop from start to end with if condition whether to print or not.